# Converting italics from XML into HTML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently learning XSLT, which I find not very easy. I have a problem converting tags that are part of a paragraph from XML into HTML. I have this kind of XML:

```
<TEI>
<teiHeader>
    <edition>
        <graphic url="#">
            <desc>Grabado calcográfico de José Ximeno y Bartolomé Vázquez <hi rend="italics">La fuerza de la sangre</hi>, edición de las <hi rend="italics">Novelas ejemplares</hi> impresa por Antonio de Sancha en Madrid, 1783.</desc>
        </graphic>
    </edition>
    <profileDesc>
        <abstract>
            <p><seg rend="italics">La fuerza de la sangre</seg> es una de las novelas más breves y más enigmáticas de Miguel de Cervantes. Sexta entre las doce <seg rend="italics">Novelas ejemplares</seg> (1613).</p>
        </abstract>
    </profileDesc>

</teiHeader>
</TEI>
```

I want to pass some of the information into HTML (the graphic thing) but other i don't (the abstrat). For converting it into HTML, I have tried several times XSLT stylesheets like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template
    match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <link href="../Styles/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <title>Información</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="graphic//desc">
    <p class="title">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italics']">
    <i>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </i>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that doesn't print the text, it does something like:

```
  <p xmlns="" class="title">
     <i></i>
     <i></i>
  </p>
```

As you can imagine, what I want is:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="../Styles/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Información</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Grabado calcográfico de José Ximeno y Bartolomé Vázquez <i>La fuerza de la sangre</i>, edición de las <i>Novelas ejemplares</i> impresa por Antonio de Sancha en Madrid, 1783.</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I have searched for close questions here, and there are some similar topics, and I have tried them but I didn't get that my xml converts into the html that I want. I would be incredibly grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the template that suppresses all text:

```
<xsl:template
    match="text()"/>
```

or narrow it down to exclude the text nodes that you want to keep :

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::desc)]"/>
```

or override it for the text nodes that you want to keep - i.e. add:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::desc]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

***in response to your edit:***

IMHO, the better strategy to follow here is to apply templates selectively. Then you won't need to suppress text nodes at all:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template match="/TEI">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="../Styles/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <title>Información</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="teiHeader/edition/graphic/desc"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="desc">
    <p class="title">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='italics']">
    <i>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </i>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also the handling of default namespace.

Comment: Hi, first of all many thanks for your answer. My xml is actually more compicated that I wrote at the beginning. I have just edited the question. As you can see now, there is also an <abstract> element that I do not want to pass into the HTML.
Your second solutions would actually work. The thing is: do you think that is the best strategy to work in general when the XML document has a lot of different elements, some of them I want them with text in my HTML, some of them I don't want them at all.
Again, many many thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the editing, opinion and code. It works perfectly and I understand what you mean. Very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The template that matches text() is empty, so it does nothing. Try this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

For me it worked when I tried it.

Comment: Such template would be redundant - the built-in template rules already do that.

Comment: Hi, first of all many many thanks, this actually works. The problem is that my xml is actually more complicated than I have said at the beginning. I have just edited. With your solutions, now it copies everything into the HTML, also the text of the elements that I do not want. How can I do to get the text of <graphic> but not the text from <abstract>? Again, thank you for you time!